# How can I make volte calls with sip softwares

Tags: sniffing, 4g, ims

I have a 4G LTE subscription in my country with a feauture to make phone calls, now with the sim the company provide us with B310-s Huwaui modem

This modem also have an FXS port, that you can plug a normal landline phone in it, and make calls using Volte

Is it possible to sniff data that it's made by the modem to make the call or another way so I can make phone calls with my computer or smartphone using a Sip software for example ? ( without having to use the landline phone or some FXO switch)

Answer (score 0):

If your modem provides an IP connection to your computer then you have the right connectivity to make SIP or other VoIP calls using a client on your computer.

However, some operators may block VoIP traffic over their mobile networks as they do not want people making voice calls this way. This is possibly less common now that it was in the past, but it would be worth checking with your operator.

Answer (score 0):

You may set a bridge between the PC and the dongle and once dongle sets up the call , fwd voice from it to PC and vice versa , similar to what we can do with mac OS and ios (Macbook to iphone) . But this may need you to have access to modem code to be able to modify the same